# How to clear form input after save?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How can I clear form input on form submit?

After URL is saved I return the view for creating a form so I can add new URL.

The problem is that this time URL is populated from previous save.

How can I empty it after save?

Isn't that the point of second parameter which is set to null?

Using laravel version 5.4.36.

In the "create" iew I have a form with URL input:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'urls.store']) !!}

    {{ Form::url('url', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}

{{ Form::submit('Add domain', array('class' => 'btn' )) }}
```

Store method saves URL to database and returns the same view:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    // URL Validation
    $this->validate($request, array(
        'url' => 'required|url|unique:urls'
        ));

    // Save
    $url = new Url;
    $url->url = $request->url;

    $url->save()

    return view('urls.create');
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about the autosave data (field has yellow background)?

Comment: return redirect('/url_that_hits_that_view');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form view should be handled by a get request on Route and submitting form is a post request .So after submitting the form you should redirect the same page not just returning the view . Check the web.php is the Routes are ok or not . Try to
add it to the store method ,I think it may help you

```
return redirect()->back();
```

or with flash message

```
return redirect('urls.create')->with('success', 'URL has been added');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make value = some values come from the controller with empty values when it's the parameters is set i.e use isset function

or 

you can make a flag in the view when it sends to controller check it if it is true means you submit the form, in this case, make the values with empty